# Can we get Equation formatting?

Tags: feature-request, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding support for math notation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4152/adding-support-for-math-notation)

CS is close enough to math that you tend to get a few questions and answers with equations in them. Also, another topic that would be cool to have [a stack exchange site for is math](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4033/what-stackexchange-sites-do-you-want-to-see/5282#5282). Based on those, it would be nice to be able to get math formatting.

Mark me as a [dup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4152/adding-support-for-math-notation): references [this solution](http://latex.codecogs.com/editor.php) that rocks

Comment: Possible dupe - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4152/adding-support-for-math-notation

Comment: Some very nice answers to that question...

Answer (score 1):

You could just try one of the sites listed here:

> http://sixthform.info/steve/wordpress/?p=59

I see no reason otherwise for SO.com to embed this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with math formatting is that a lot of it requires something like rendering LaTeX images (like Wikipedia does), which is expensive on the server side (especially for live editing), or using something like MathML, which some browsers don't support.