# Latex Support Like Math Overflow

Tags: feature-request, latex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding support for math notation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4152/adding-support-for-math-notation)

Well, I realize this has probably been asked a googol times but I'm going to ask anyways, because the squeaky wheel gets the grease. Can we please have latex support for Stack Overflow so those ugly pseudo code lines or proofs of algorithms can start looking presentable?

I often answer math-related programming questions on SO, and so pretty much every answer I post I feel a distinct lack of latex. For example: [Finding the intersection of 3 spheres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406375/finding-intersection-points-between-3-spheres/1407395#1407395).

Before someone responds "those people really should be asking those math-related question on Math Overflow" let me ask you "have you ever visited Math Overflow and read any of the questions?" If you ask a question like that on MO you will be immediately closed for asking a trivial question. Math Overflow is designed for mathematicians, not for the lay man. Though I feel Stack Overflow would benefit greatly from latex support simply because of readability reasons.

Moreover, since MO already implemented latex support, it is a solved problem and just a matter of asking  them how they did it. The amount of effort required to implement this should be minimal.

Comment: Duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30559/latex-in-stack-overflow and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12700/add-latex-support-to-markdown-wmd and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4152/adding-support-for-math-notation

Comment: and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8551/can-we-get-equation-formatting and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12918/can-we-have-a-ruling-on-latex-on-stackoverflow

Comment: bravo you discovered a duplicate! I actually explicitly stated I knew it was a duplicate, I'm just trying to get the grease

Comment: It's better to bump an existing question (either by editing it or posting a new answer) rather than post a duplicate. Admitting that it is a duplicate doesn't really help.

Comment: @ChrisF: 12918 is unrelated to this.

Comment: @KennyTM - oops, you're right. My apologies.

Comment: @ChrisF: Logically when the SO dev's are deciding to add a feature, they run a search on meta feature requests and tally the total number of requests for a given feature. So yes, duplicates help in this particular case.

Comment: @gmatt: I don't think it works like that. At least sum up the votes.

Comment: @gmatt: They are more likely to treat the highest voted single question as indicative of the total support. Why? Because they have every reason to think that the *same* people will be voting in favor of every duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

LaTeX is nice, but <del>ASCII</del> Unicode art isn't that unreadable either

```
       x² + y² = r₁²
   (d-h)² + h² = r₂²
                   ,———————————————————————————
                  /       ( r₁² - r₂² + d² )²
⇒          h =   /  r₁² - ———————————————————
                √                 4 d²
```

(and you've missed a factor of 4 in the answer.)

Comment: The problem is that expert LaTeX users can **type** something that look nice in a fraction of the time needed to do a nice ASCII artwork. Writing a single McLaurin series expansion on SO is a PITA, let alone writing some math passages to someone in order to explain him a math-related algorithm.