# How much customization will be supported on new Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, area-51, stackexchange-2.0

I'm trying to get members of my old Go club interested in the [Game of Go](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11942/game-of-go?referrer=f6ULDdedUma37ioaqR_AEA2) proposal on Area 51 and one of the first questions that came up was whether or not it would support posting board positions.  I mentioned that there was built-in imgur.com support, but everyone agreed that a built-in board editor would be much more preferable.  It wouldn't be necessary to actually play a game with someone over the site.  Just an editor where you can set up a board position and play through different lines by yourself prior to posting would be plenty of functionality for asking/answering Go questions.  (Something like [GoWiki](http://senseis.xmp.net/?GoWiki) could be used to store the position as text, but present the diagram as an image.)

[Math notation support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4152/adding-support-for-math-notation) was already added to the [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) site and that was extremely well-received.  I can see customizations being useful for the [Chess](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7551/chess) and [Board and Card Games](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5220/board-and-card-games) proposals as well.  Are any other customizations specific to a given site being planned?

(Also, is there a better way to suggest customizations for a site than posting here on Meta?  Is there some way in Area 51 to share these suggestions on a site proposal itself?)

Comment: Sometimes you can discuss those suggestions in the comments on the proposal (if it's still in the definition stage). But otherwise, this is the place to ask things about anything that is still in Area 51, especially if it is something that can be applied to multiple sites.

Comment: don't forget music notation, electrical circuits -- heck, everything LaTeX supports!

Comment: @Grace: Thanks.  I was hoping it would be okay to discuss it here instead of waiting for the site to get launched to bring it up on the site-specific meta.  My fear is that some people will be reluctant to commit to a site (and it won't get launched) if certain customizations aren't addressed.

Comment: @Tobias: Yes!  I can see music notation definitely being useful on more than one site.  Hopefully the team can leverage the work already done on the Mathematics notation to make that happen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general we are favoring JavaScript solutions for situations like this. Sort of like MathJax but not *obscenely heavy* like MathJax, hopefully.

- on the Poker site, display hand notation as poker hands
- on the Go site, display Go notation as go boards
- on the Chess site, display Chess notation as chess boards
- on the Airplane Pilots site, display three letter uppercase [airport designations](http://www.airport-technology.com/codes/A.html) as special links

... and so forth.

I am also open to text post-processors that run on submitted edits/posts.

Answer (score 5):

Should everything else fail... unicode for the rescue!

```
                  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┐ A 
├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤ B 
├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─○─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤ C
├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─○─●─○─┼─┼─┼─┤ D
├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─○─●─●─○─┼─┼─┤ E
├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─○─●─●─○─┼─┤ F
├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─○─●─┼─┼─┤ G
├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤ H
├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤ I
├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤ J
├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤ K
├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤ L
├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤ M
├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤ N
├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤ O
├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤ P
├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤ Q
├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤ R
└─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘ S
```

Comment: This is a great example.  It made me immediately realize that a good Go editor should prevent you from creating impossible positions.  ;)

Comment: @Bill lol, good point :D