# MathJax support for Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, markdown, mathjax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding support for math notation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4152/adding-support-for-math-notation)

Why is it that MathJax is supported on [Math Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/), but not on Stack Overflow?

Since we need to express equations on SO as well, MathJax should be supported.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding support for math notation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4152/adding-support-for-math-notation/60023#60023)