# Could SE profile and hot questions support MathJax for titles and summaries?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange-button, hot-questions, network-profile, mathjax

I guess not, but just in case it's easily fixed: could the hot questions and SE profile support MathJax to render question titles and summaries?

On most SE sites, the SE MultiCollider does not support MathJax, and [neither do](https://stackexchange.com/users/510889) the global SE profiles:

[image: Global Inbox without MathJax support]

[image: Global SE profile without MathJax support]

Of course, the specific site itself supports [the very same title](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36083/prove-that-displaystyle-lim-x-rightarrow-1-fracx1-m-1x1-n-1-fracn) just fine:

[image: Global Inbox with MathJax support]

[image: Hottest questions with MathJax support]

I know support for this on the regular sites [has been declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4152/adding-support-for-math-notation/60023#60023), *"as it is an extremely heavy dependency"*. But maybe it's still doable *just for rendering* the titles and summaries? Or maybe only on the global SE profile? (Careers might like this too? Never used that.)

Comment: Or maybe just remove the `\displaystyle`? (I wonder about the URL slug too, but I have no better idea than just stripping the odd `displaystyle` from `prove-that-displaystyle-lim-x-rightarrow-1-fracx1-m-1x1-n-1-fracn`. But well, any resulting slug for the title *"prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{x^{1/m}-1}{x^{1/n}-1}=\frac{n}{m}$"* would still be odd I guess. `;-)`)

Comment: Awww, math formulas also hard to read just like [Golfscript](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/678/decipher-a-vigenere-ciphertext/712#712) for me.

Comment: Ah, the `\displaystyle` is not in all titles. That's [much better](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MDtcV.png) already: `Intuitive explanation for the identity $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n {k^3} = \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k\right)^2$` and [a better slug](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61482/intuitive-explanation-for-the-identity-sum-limits-k-1n-k3-left-sum-li) too: `/intuitive-explanation-for-the-identity-sum-limits-k-1n-k3-left-sum-li`. No changes for the example in the question though. Maybe it's cached?

Comment: Too bad: enabling it might even be [a breaking change](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203999/markdown-rendering-font-weirdly).

Comment: This seems to be status-declined as per Nick's investigations [in November 2013](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203977/theres-seriously-no-reason-why-latex-markup-via-mathjax-shouldnt-be-enabled-on/204003#204003).

Answer (score 14):

If MathJax cannot be enabled on non-MathJax sites, then maybe render a title such as:

> Prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{x^{1/m}-1}{x^{1/n}-1}=\frac{n}{m}$

...on non-MathJax sites as:

```
Prove that <img src=...>
```

...where the image URL is taken from `$ [...] $`:

```
https://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?[...]
```

Like:

> Prove that [image]

(And some CSS to align the image, which might be hard as `vertical-align: middle` does not quite fix it...)

Answer (score 11):

The problem with doing that is that the MathJax dependency is a very heavy one, and with your proposal it'd have to be loaded on *all* pages of *all* sites.

What would be ideal is if it there was some sort of approximate LaTeX → Unicode translator in C# to make a display-friendlier representation of equations, bringing

```
$\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{x^{1/m}-1}{x^{1/n}-1}=\frac{n}{m}$
```

to (e.g.)

```
lim(x→1) (x^(1/m)-1)/(x^(1/n)-1) = n/m
```

Comment: And no, I lack the know-how to make one.

Comment: Any idea if it's heavy in basically loading the script, or only when actually rendering? (Rendering would only occur when opening the MultiCollider thingy, or when looking at a global SE profile that happens to use MathJax, and then only for titles and summaries, not for full-blown posts?)

Comment: @Arjan It's heavy when loading, as it needs to download all the fonts AFAIK

Comment: Maybe such Unicode title might even be the base for a better URL slug. Too bad @badp cannot make it ;-)

Comment: @badp:  Just wanted to mention that you may be confusing what MathJax has to load on pages that _don't_ include math with the loading for those page that _do_.  Fonts are not loaded on pages that don't include mathematics.  MathJax can be configured in many ways, but the usual approach is to load only the core MathJax.js file plus a configuration file.  These are shipped gzipped from the MathJax CDN, and the files used at math.se when gzipped are less than 50KB total (smaller than the css file used here).  For pages that include math, more has to be loaded, but this not for non-math pages.

Comment: Also, the configuration file used on math.se includes a number of parts that could be left out of the configuration that is loaded on all pages (letting those be loaded on demand when needed).  That could reduce MathJax's footprint for non-math pages even further.  I haven't calculated it, but suspect you could cut it in half.

Comment: It looks like about 16KB (after gzip) is possible for a minimal configuration.  On the other hand, if you are going to be identifying mathematics and processing it yourself, why not simply identify it and include MathJax only on those pages that have math?  No ned to do other processing, and you get the heavy download only when it is required.  With the CDN and caching, I think this would give you reasonable performance.

Comment: @dpvc [It's not me you have to convince](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4152/adding-support-for-math-notation/60023#60023); I'm just proposing an alternative. :)

Comment: `What would be ideal is if it there was some sort of approximate LaTeX → Unicode translator in C# to make a display-friendlier representation of equations, bringing [MathJax]
to (e.g.) [actual mathematical notation]` That can be easily done manually with the help of backticks. Yay for `<code>` and `<pre>`!