# MathJax rendering in Hot Network Questions sidebar

Tags: bug, hot-questions, mathjax

I've come across this oddity while perusing the Physics stack. The linked question is [what is the command [ -s “$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh” ] && . “$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh” doing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/244732), being that due to the dollar signs on both sides, MathJax was triggered. I'm not sure if this is intended behavior, hence the post.

Oddly enough, after trying several times (reloading the page, visiting other pages), I was unable to reproduce the issue.

Related: [Exclude TeX.SE question titles from MathJax parsing in Hot Network Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229363/233426)

[image: MahJax rendering]

Comment: See also [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22030/bug-looks-like-mathjax-is-eating-up-dollars-signs-in-hot-network-questions)

Comment: @ShadowWizard while the problems described appear to be the same, the possible duplicate has yet to be solved, closed, or at the very least, to have an accepted answer.

Comment: Not really @Dok here on MSE when there are same requests, one is closed as dupe of the other, regardless of its state.

Comment: Okay then, just wanted to report this and (possibly) to give this a little more attention.