# Site-specific MathJax affects all sites' question titles in front page hot network questions list

Tags: bug, hot-questions, mathjax, homepage

I noticed while browsing Worldbuilding's front page that the hot network questions list seems to use Mathjax globally for question titles, even when the site the question is from doesn't use Mathjax, leading to unexpected results.

See for example the Server Fault question here:

[image]

The real title of that particular question is `Get-ADGroupMember $Group fails when $Group contains principals from other domains`.

Hence:

- Question titles from sites that do not have Mathjax enabled should not be rendered using Mathjax, even if the site the list is being rendered on/for has Mathjax enabled.
- Questions from sites that *do* have Mathjax enabled should have their titles rendered using Mathjax, *ideally* regardless of whether the site the list is being rendered on/for has Mathjax enabled or not *but* at least on sites where Mathjax is enabled.

Comment: Noticed after posting this that [Exclude TeX.SE question titles from MathJax parsing in Hot Network Questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229363/exclude-tex-se-question-titles-from-mathjax-parsing-in-hot-network-questions) seems to be about much the same issue, though focuses more on TeX SE than on the general problem. It may or may not count as a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, it's related enough to be a duplicate. You can leave this one as well (i.e. don't delete it) so that future search will be easier. :)