# MathJax doesn't work on global filtered questions

Tags: bug, tag-filters, mathjax

MathJax works perfectly on Math.SE, MO, etc., but when I see aggregated feed here ([example filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/255045/math)), it doesn't work:

[image]

Is there a way to enable MathJax there?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen similar requests get declined before, because SE doesn't want to load MathJax on sites that don't actually use it for their content. But I guess the SE.com portal probably sees little enough traffic, and enough links to questions on sites using MathJax, that loading it there might be justifiable. Of course, [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229363/exclude-tex-se-question-titles-from-mathjax-parsing-in-hot-network-questions) would probably need to be fixed first.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: It's strange because Math.SE is one of the most popular SE site. Why SE doesn't want to load MathJax on all sites? Why not to make an option for switch?! SE is basically an *aggregator*, it should succesfully aggregate posts from any SE site, isn't it?