# Filter sites are not responsive

Tags: feature-request, design, stackexchange.com, tag-filters, responsive-design

Viewing questions from a global filter (like [this one](https://stackexchange.com/filters/252485/math)) looks like this on my mobile device:
[image: filter sites on mobile]

My requests:

- Please make filter sites responsive, so I don't have to zoom and scroll horizontally when I use them on a mobile device.
- As already requested [in another post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284446/mathjax-doesnt-work-on-global-filtered-questions?r=SearchResults), please enable MathJax on the filter sites, so that questions from sites that use MathJax (like Mathematics SE) are rendered properly.

Comment: I think most of the stackexchange.com network site has not been updated in ages, even though every Stack Exchange network site (and most pages on them) have since been updated to be responsive.