# Formula markup being parsed in the hot questions sidebar when it's the first item in the list

Tags: bug, markdown, mathjax, sidebar

Just saw [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338834/what-is-wrong-with-chcao-s-h2o-l-ca2-aq-2-oh-aq) in the hot questions sidebar on a Worldbuilding post, and it was parsed as a formula, but after updating the page it went to a different position where it didn't get parsed. I couldn't F5 enough times for it to appear in the first slot to confirm and get a screenshot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude TeX.SE question titles from MathJax parsing in Hot Network Questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229363/exclude-tex-se-question-titles-from-mathjax-parsing-in-hot-network-questions)

Comment: Yea it's not a dupe. It only happens when the item is the first in the list.