# Hot Network Questions uses LaTeX if title has $ in it

Tags: bug

Hot Network Questions renders `$USER$` in this AskUbuntu question as LaTeX, when it is viewed in Biology.

There is an [earlier question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229363/exclude-tex-se-question-titles-from-mathjax-parsing-in-hot-network-questions) which proposes question titles that intentionally have LaTeX are excluded from the Hot Network Questions. According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239881/345300), this has already been done.

In this case, the original site does not support LaTeX in titles.

[image]