# Broken MathJax from Math site in HNQ

Tags: bug, hot-questions, mathjax

I saw [this Math question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2789441) (now deleted) in the Hot Network Questions:

[image: \begin{equation*} \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow(0,0)} \frac{3}{x^2 +2 y^2} \end{equation*}]

(This screenshot is of the stackexchange.com Hot Questions list.)

The title is also illegible on **all** sites when it appears in the HNQ sidebar, including the Math site.

Last time I checked, [questions that use MathJax in the title should not become hot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108166/323179), but I think what's messing it up is the fact that it uses `\begin{equation*}` instead of the standard delimiters (i.e. `$` or `\$`). Note that the MathJax [renders properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkmaZ.png) in the title.