# Markdown rendering font weirdly

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, markdown-rendering

While looking at a [close review item](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3201006), this looked rather weird:

> [image]

So I took a look at it on [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19553377/447356), and it didn't look the same:

> [image]

Here's the edit page:

> [image]

Is this a bug?

Comment: That looks like something's thrown MathJax into the review page.

Comment: Can you link to the review? Also, do you have any LaTeX-rendering plugins?

Comment: Hmm, no-repro now, sucks. http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3201006

Comment: LaTeX broke the suspension tool for a bit, too. :D

Comment: @minitech: you mods really enjoy stamping on littluns, don't you?

Comment: @Anna nice tag but make it mod-only so it won't get removed by mistake. ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Nick Craver was testing MathJax performance for an answer to [a request for MathJax to be enabled on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203977/theres-seriously-no-reason-why-latex-markup-via-mathjax-shouldnt-be-enabled-on). It looks like you stumbled into an edit that inadvertently triggered MathJax to typeset an equation.

Comment: Oops...sorry :(

Comment: @Nick so how is the performance? :)

Comment: But Nick wrote *even when "it's not doing anything"* ;-)