# Why isn't mathjax supported?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I suppose the question is pretty self explanatory.

I can think of a plethora of examples (discussing mathematical algorithms: applied math: analysis of a problem, etc...) where math formatting would be helpful.

And sites such as math.stackexchange and cs theory.stackexchange support it.

So why not stack overflow?

Comment: [This is why.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203999/223030)