# Should MathJaX be enabled on the hot questions list?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions, mathjax

Currently, when a question that includes MathJaX in the title is on the hot questions list found on the Stack Exchange front page, the raw MathJaX is displayed, and not the nicely formatted math.

Should this be changed, or should users just refrain from putting MathJaX in question titles?

To clarify, I'm talking about the hot network questions list found when you visit [the Stack Exchange front page](https://stackexchange.com), ***not the sidebar on sites***. The sidebar is a whole different issue.

Comment: @200_success How is this a duplicate?

Comment: It's already known to be buggy. This is just a different way of phrasing the same complaint.

Comment: @200_success If you read the linked post, you will see it asks to __exclude__ titles from MathJax processing, not to add this processing. And not on this list, but in the sidebar of sites where MathJax is enabled.

Comment: This would require every site on the SE network to load MathJax. The reason MathJax isn't already enabled on every site on the network is that it causes a significant increase in page load times. The tradeoff is worth it for sites that _need_ MathJax, like Math.SE; the tradeoff is assuredly not worth it for sites that just want Hot Network Questions to render right. Pretty sure this is going to end up [meta-tag:status-declined].

Comment: @senshin See my edit.

Comment: @Quill Well, yes, he is talking about that now that he edited his post to clarify that in response to my comment.

Comment: Enabling MathJax in hot questions would imply enabling it on all sites.  This isn't going to happen because of the resources such would require to even render a basic page that doesn't have any mathjax on it.  See [There's seriously no reason why LaTeX markup via MathJax shouldn't be enabled on SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252282/) for the testing where it increase page load time by 21% and was a (in 2013) an additional 82h/day of additional load time and 3M more requests. It would also be a [breaking change](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203999/) on some sites.

Comment: @MichaelT,  Please take another look at the edited question, and in particular the clarification at the end.  This suggestion does not imply enabling MathJax on all sites.

Comment: It's good to note, MathJax in titles is discouraged in chem.SE due to searchability issues, ugly URL slugs and Google messes. See [this](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/253/should-we-revisit-the-url-slug-issue) for example.

Comment: @D.W. it is *still* a [breaking change](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203999/) on the front page for Stack Exchange.  You've got a choice - do Math.SE MathJax titles render correctly? or Stack Overflow question titles render correctly?