# MathJax doesn't always work in question lists

Tags: bug, mathjax

MathJax in question lists.  Yay!  But sometimes it works

[image]

and sometimes it doesn't.

[image]

Seems as if the MathJax is being truncated prematurely, and therefore doesn't render.  Is there a reasonable fix for this?

Comment: I assume both screen captures are from [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/)? (If *not* from the same site, then maybe related: [Could SE profile and hot questions support MathJax for titles and summaries?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89437/could-se-profile-and-hot-questions-support-mathjax-for-titles-and-summaries), where in May 2011 the answer was: no. And Nick confirmed that "no" [in November 2013](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203977/theres-seriously-no-reason-why-latex-markup-via-mathjax-shouldnt-be-enabled-on/204003#204003).)

Comment: @arjan: Both screen shots are from Mathematics.

Comment: A *reasonable* fix?  Not really, we'd have to substnatially complicate the snippet showing code.  I'll take a look, but it basically means reproducing the outer pathjax parser - will have to see what expense that adds.  It would also need some logic so that *huge* equations are still left out, which we can't easily determine based on character counts alone.

Comment: @Nick Yeah, I kinda figured it would be a non-trivial fix.