# Oneboxing should take into account whether the source uses MathJax

Tags: feature-request, bug, chat, onebox, mathjax

While it's reasonable to not add MathJax to chat ([Any chance of MathJax in chat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97938/any-chance-of-mathjax-in-chat)), one-boxing does all the heavy-lifting once, on the server, so those reasons don't apply.

And currently all posts making use of MathJax look severly broken when oneboxed.
So, could oneboxing please consider whether the source uses MathJax or something else similarly exotic and apply it on the server?

A chat-message trying to onebox a post on [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) ([The differences between the return times to a recurrent state of a discrete Markov chain are independent and identically distributed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1492342/the-differences-between-the-return-times-to-a-recurrent-state-of-a-discrete-mark)):

> [image: Post on Math.SE]

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't understand what exactly you want to be implemented. There is currently no way to make that onebox work except for adding MathJax to chat. MathJax is always done on the client the way SE uses it, not on the server.

Comment: Actually, your proposal to go for full server-side MathJax-interpretation (for everything but editing) is better, so I upvoted that: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268308/implement-server-side-mathjax-rendering It has a broader impact and should generally improve all MathJax-using sites' performance.