# How about adding MathJax to Hot Questions on stackexchange.com?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, hot-questions, mathjax

Almost always in [Hot Questions](https://stackexchange.com/questions) on the StackExchange.com site there are questions from Math.SE, so I think it would be so much better to have these questions rendered correctly instead of reading the ugly stuff like this:

[image: Math.SE example questions]

When it's not rendered it's hard to check with a single glance if that question is interesting for someone or not. So maybe you could load MathJax only if there are questions from Math.SE (or other scientific sites that are using equations) or something smarter just to make these interesting questions a little bit more interesting.

**Edit:** Just to make it more clear, I'm talking about adding MathJax only on this page: https://stackexchange.com/questions, since there are a lot of questions that are coming from Math.SE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Latex in Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30559/latex-in-stack-overflow) (through [MathJax should also work in StackOverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106281/164403)).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi not exactly duplicate.. I'm not talking about SO I'm talking only about the specific link that I've provided..

Comment: I was thinking the "extremely heavy dependency" argument still applied, but you're right: your question's scope is not the same.

Comment: Well this _extremely heavy dependency_ I think we can live with.. It can be done lazily.. but I think the quality of that particular page will increase.. :)

Answer (score 11):

This isn't really an issue anymore. The current list doesn't display the beginning of the question body (compare the screenshot below with the one in the question) and [questions with MathJax in their title are excluded from the Hot Network Questions list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239881/295232) so rendering issues don't happen anymore.

[image]