# Add LaTeX support to Stack Exchange sites

Tags: support, latex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding support for math notation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4152/adding-support-for-math-notation)

I noticed that [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) supports LaTeX.

Why not include LaTeX support on all Stack Exchange sites?

I need to represent a matrix when I encountered a problem in a NumPy matrix manipulation in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Latex is a specialized language for exact layouts and is specifically suitable for mathematical notation.

Therefore, it makes sense to support it in a math website, but not much elsewhere.

I have seen people use [ASCII art](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art) when representing matrices on SO.

Comment: If Latex support does not influence performance much, I don't think it will complicate user operations. So it will be better if other stackoverflow sites(that will involve some math,like the main site) support Latex

Comment: @xiaohan2012 - "If". And if it does? From what I understand, the support is done via a java tex interpreted.

Comment: "Therefore, it makes sense to support it in a math website, but not much elsewhere." and how can you be so certain of that? There are many stackexchange sites solving problems with math. Math is used to solve and endless amount of real life problems, why should only mathematicians have this possibility?

Comment: @MaxKielland - MathJax is enabled on the Astronomy, Biology, Chemistry, Cognitive Sciences, Cryptography, Computer Sciences, CS Theory, DSP, Economics, Electronics, Ham Radio, Machine Learning, Physics, Quant, Robotics, Computational Sciences, Space Exploration, Statistics and Theoretical Physics Stack Exchange sites (as well as the Mathematics related ones). These are the sites where mathematics and mathematical notations are seen as needed tools.

Comment: Programming related problems and solutions are often expressed with mathematics. Even photography may use math to express focal points or other optical effects used by photographers. My point is that you can't say that math isn't used on other sites, just because you don't see any use of it there. However, I found this APP to do the LaTex interpretation on the client side https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/se-chat-mathjax/jkohnpfocfllikbgkfdcghgjgejcfhjb?hl=en&gl=US