# Insert some Latex code in a question

Tags: feature-request, latex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding support for math notation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4152/adding-support-for-math-notation)
>   [Latex in Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30559/latex-in-stack-overflow)

In many sites of the Stack Exchange network there is the possibility to insert some Latex code directly in your question (i.e. MathJaX equations $\sin^2 \theta$).

I tried this on SO but the result wasn't as expected.

What is, if exists, the command for inserting a complex equation in Latex?

E.g.

z = \sum_{k=1}^{|{\cal N}*l|} \alpha*{k}e^{-\frac{\left\| (\Bxs,\Bys) - \mu_k(\Bxs,\Bys) \right\|^2}{2{\sigma_k(\Bxs,\Bys)^2} } }

If not existing, do you think it could be a useful feature?

Comment: How is this different to all the other requests for LaTex support on Stack Overflow which are listed over there on the right --->?

Comment: @ChrisF - I checked some of them, but they seemed to me much more a discussion over this issue, rather than proposing an answer to a specific issue. Anywayif you say they answer my problem I'll check better, maybe I just didn't have the correct attention.

Comment: Well the answer is that you can't insert LaTex code and while it *might* be a useful feature it has been declined. Also, if your question is about LaTex why not post it on the [tex.se] site?

Comment: @ChrisF - My [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658799/plot-a-grid-of-gaussians-with-matlab/13658857#13658857) is not on LaTex...But I really would have appreciated using it instead of taking a snapshot of the equation... ;)

Comment: If you *need* a lot of math--especially kid of math that gets complicated markup--your questions may be suitable for Math.se or csTheory.SE where they *do* have MathJax support.